# Difference between [range(5)] and list(range(5))

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to make a list through a range() using 2 different methods,

When I run it in python terminal, it return `False`

```
list(range(5))==[range(5)]

>>> list(range(5))
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> [range(5)]
[range(0, 5)]
```

I expect the output of `[range(5)] = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]`,
but it was `[range(0, 5)]`

Comment: I think you might be looking for `[*range(5)]` with the unpacking operator.

Comment: Yes it works would you tell me some more details about it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`list()` is a function call, it takes an *iterator* as input and *converts* it into a list.

`[]` simply *wraps* whatever we put inside the bracket with a list.

So counter to your example, `list(32)` will throw an error but `[32]` will make a list with 32 as its element.

Comment: >>> [range(5)]=[range(0, 5)]   what is this